# Condition for orthonormal set to be basis of Hilbert space

Tags: hilbert-spaces

Let $H$ be a hilbert space. And let$ B$ be a basis of $H$. I think a orthonormal set$ S$ to be a basis iff $|S| =|B|$. (But I'm not sure about this) Am I right? If this is wrong, is the same argument right under the condition $H$ is separable?

The original problem is this.

Let ${e_n}$ is an orthonormal basis for a separable Hilbert space. ${f_n}$ is an orthnormal set such that $\Sigma ||e_n - f_n|| <1 $. Then prove ${f_n}$ is a basis.

Can I ask you a Hint for this?
Thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT:

Let $v$ be a vector perpendicular to all the $f_n$'s.

We have 
$$||v||^2 = \sum_n |\langle v, e_n\rangle|^2 = \sum_n |\langle v, e_n -f_n\rangle |^2 \le ||v||^2 \cdot \sum_n ||e_n - f_n||^2$$

Now $\sum_n ||e_n - f_n||^2 < 1$ ( this weaker inequality is all we need) and from the above get $||v||^2\le 0$, and so $v=0$.

Comment: Then we do not need the condition $f_n$ is orthonormal. Thank you :)

Comment: The remaining part is using {f_n} perp is 0 and M perp perp is closure of span( M). Right?

Comment: @user277793: No worries...Yes, indeed, we simply prove that the set $(f_n)$ is total.  Now $f_n$ orthonormal is used if we want to check that it's an orthonormal basis ( we would also use the result you quoted above).

Answer (score 3):

Your argument is not correct, even when $H$ is a separable Hilbert space.
Take, as a counter example, $H=\ell^2(\mathbb{N})$. Then, $(e_i)_{i \in \mathbb{N}}$ is an orthonormal basis, but $(e_{2i})_{i \in \mathbb{N}}$ is not.

For your original problem, see this question:
[orthonormal system in a Hilbert space](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/64676/orthonormal-system-in-a-hilbert-space?rq=1)